# File not found exceptions regardless of how the file is referenced

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found, pack-uri

I have a String to Img converter for displaying images in a DataGrid based on results of various methods that run, but for a reason I can't get my head around why my code can't find the images.

This is my converter, testing various different paths to PNGs that are all in /img/

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    BitmapImage image = null;
    var str = value.ToString();
    //TODO Use new icons
    if (str == "pass")
    {
        image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/img/Icon-Pass.png"));
    }
    if (str == "fail")
    {
        image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/../img/Icon-Fail.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    if (str == "warning")
    {
        image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../img/Icon-Warning.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    if (str == "notapplicable")
    {
        image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/AppName;component/img/Icon-NonApplicable.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    return image;
}
```

My project's structure is:

```
AppRoot/
├─ Helpers/
│  ├─ ImgConverter.cs
├─ img/
│  ├─ Icon-Pass.png
│  ├─ Icon-Fail.png
│  ├─ Icon-Warning.png
│  ├─ Icon-NonApplicable.png
```

But with all of these I get a mixture of File not found, directory not found and cannot locate resource exceptions

I can only assume I'm missing something dumb obvious, but I think I'm too deep to see it.

***Edit - Resolved
For the pack Uris to work, the Buid action for the images must be set to "Resource". Thanks @KlausGütter :)***

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Pieterjan I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Version 17.3.4 on Server 2022 DC (21H2). But this app that the image converter is part of is for everything from 2012r2 and up.

Comment: For the **pack** Uris to work, the Buid action for the images must be set to "Resource"

Comment: @KlausGütter ++ I knew it was something stupid! Thank you :)